# Getting invalid syntax at beginning of line

Tags: python

```
import math

key_freq1 = input()

r = (math.pow(2, (1/12))

key_freq2 = key_freq1 * r^1.0

key_freq3 = key_freq2 * r^2.0

key_freq4 = key_freq3 * r^3.0

key_freq5 = key_freq4 * r^4.0

print('{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}'.format(key_freq1, key_freq2, key_freq3, key_freq4, key_freq5))
```

the error:

```
File "main.py", line 6
    key_freq2 = key_freq1 * r^1.0
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: There is missing closing parenthesis on the previous line.

Comment: The previous line `r = (math.pow(2, (1/12))` is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: r = math.pow(2, (1/12))

Comment: Yes, on balance I think you have an extra opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this line `r = (math.pow(2, (1/12))` it should be `r = (math.pow(2, (1/12)))`
There is another issue with input. You should convert your input into `float`

**Complete Code:**

```
import math

key_freq1 = float(input())

r = (math.pow(2, (1/12)))

key_freq2 = key_freq1 * r ** 1.0

key_freq3 = key_freq2 * r ** 2.0

key_freq4 = key_freq3 * r ** 3.0

key_freq5 = key_freq4 * r ** 4.0

print('{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}'.format(key_freq1, key_freq2, key_freq3, key_freq4, key_freq5))
```

**Input:**

```
10
```

**Output:**

```
10.00 10.59 11.89 14.14 17.82
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `^` as exponent operator then replace it with `**` (double steric).

Like this:

```
key_freq2 = key_freq1 * r**1.0
```

Comment: yeah I fixed the syntax and figured that part out on my own lol. thanks